# Get submitted form class in jQuery (materializeCSS & Laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, materialize

I have a Laravel project with a page with 5 modals(MaterializeCSS), each modal has a form. When I submit the form and run into any validation errors the modal has to reopen.

I can achieve this by running the following code :

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#modal-entry').modal('open');
    });
@endif
```

But this only works for one modal. And it needs to work for every modal.

I found this script to reopen the right modal by going through a switch. But I need to find out how I can have some kind of identifier from the submitted form to go through the switch.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const reopenModal = '';
            switch (reopenModal) {
                case 'thing1':
                    $('#modal-entry').modal('open');
                    break;
                case 'thing2':
                    $('#modal-edit').modal('open');
                    break;
                default:
            }
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

How can I get an unique variable from the submitted posts to use in my `switch`?

Comment: You would need for PHP to pass back some information about which form was submitted.  Is there any identifiers in the forms which is posted to the server which would allow you to determine which form was submitted, and pass that back to the view?

Comment: @user3158900 yes, every form has <input type="text" `value="modal-start" name="type" hidden>` where the value is the modal name. How would I get this data back?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already rendering your view with an error variable, why don't you just have a hidden field on your form that holds a form identifier, pass that to your controller and then render your view with the variable and do something like.

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#{{$theModalIdPassedToMyController}}').modal('open');
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: Could you maybe show me how the hidden field would look? an ID of my modal is `modal-entry` for example.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="modal-id" value="modal-entry">

Comment: I found that! Thanks. Now I just need to know how to get this variable back to the page without successfully submitting.

Comment: You could use a `try {//do the thing you want} catch(\Exception $e) { return view($modalIdSentFromRequest);}`